# Making my POS : Error on DataGridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, odbc

I am trying to make a simple POS system with VB.NET, but since I don't know how to start, i ask for my friends to give me sample source code. I planning to use MySQL for my database rather than Microsoft Access because our school uses it.
Below is a sample code of the source code :

```
Public Sub FillDGVWithReceiptInfo(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
        DGV.Rows.Clear()
        Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter

        For i = 0 To Me.ReceiptDetailsList.Count - 1
            Dim T1 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).Barcode
            Dim T2 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ItemBuyPrice
            Dim T3 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ItemCount
            Dim T4 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ItemSellPrice
            Dim T5 = T3 * T4
            Dim T6 = TA.GetDataByBarcode(T1).Rows(0).Item("ItemName")

            DGV.Rows.Add(T1, T6, T2, T4, T3, T5)

        Next
    End Sub
```

i am trying to convert it to an "OdBC" kind of format. so i came up with this (also, this is the part where i get some error) :

```
  Public Sub FillDGVWithReceiptInfo(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
        DGV.Rows.Clear()

        For i = 0 To Me.ReceiptDetailsList.Count - 1
            Dim T1 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ganoProdID
            Dim T3 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ItemCount
            Dim T4 = Me.ReceiptDetailsList(i).ganoItemPrice
            Dim T5 = T3 * T4

            Dim TA As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gano_inventory WHERE gano_proID = " & T1 & ";", conn)
            Dim R As New DataTable
            TA.Fill(R)

            Dim T6 = R.Rows(0).Item("gano_item")

            DGV.Rows.Add(T1, T6, T4, T3, T5)

        Next
    End Sub
```

this is the code's error :
*No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.* in this line :  **DGV.Rows.Add(T1, T6, T4, T3, T5)**

can someone please help me with it? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the columns before you add the Rows.

```
DGV.Columns.Add("ProdId")
DGV.Columns.Add("Item")
DGV.Columns.Add("ItemPrice")
DGV.Columns.Add("ItemCount")
DGV.Columns.Add("Total")
```

...

```
For i = 0 ...
  DGV.Rows.Add(...
```